# How to simulate "drawing" with Selenium WebDriver (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drawing, openlayers

I have this GIS API that works on top of OpenLayers. I want to perform freehand drawings like in [this example](http://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/bpBRJL):

[image: freehand line]

I want to simulate this freehand drawing with Selenium WebDriver (Java version) and I have tried this:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(source);    // 'source' is a WebElement
act.clickAndHold();
act.moveByOffset(5, 0);
act.moveByOffset(10, 5);
act.moveByOffset(20, 10);
act.moveByOffset(30, 15);
act.moveByOffset(-10, 20);
act.release();
act.build().perform();
```

But it seems, that the click is released after the first `moveByOffset`.

I also tried this:

```
new Actions(driver)
        .clickAndHold(source)
        .moveByOffset(50,-20)
        .moveByOffset(100,0)
        .release()
        .build()
        .perform();
```

But I get basically the same result.

The click is released before all the moves are performed. I am quite certain that this is possible and that I am the one who is doing it the wrong way.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: after each move use wait like this: act.moveByOffset(5, 0);
  act.wait(3000);
  act.moveByOffset(10, 5);

this wait will completer ur action and than go for the next action.

Comment: @noor, thanks, but it is still not working... I think the clickAndHold() is not even working... it draws nothing... the "wait" tip you gave didn't work either...

Comment: so than after clickandhold, use perfom and than use other code with wait. ur  code seems ok but only prob is action is not happening sequentially.

Comment: @noor, still not working... could you provide an example, please? what do you mean when you say the action is nit happening sequentially? when I call "build()", isn't it supposed to join all the actions in order? thanks again

Comment: actually though u use build and its not working, thats why i told about ur action. ok now i am trying on my own machine and will let u know.

Comment: can u pls provide ur "source" locator? , it will save my time

Comment: sorry, but my website is not online yet... can't you use the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/bpBRJL)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106376/discussion-between-joaorodr84-and-noor).

Comment: Hi @joaorodr84 Were you able to find any solution for the question? I am trying to draw a polygon in my google map using selenium and Java. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I was not able to solve it, but check out the conversation link in the above comment. @noor provided a good answer.